# How to import file from another python project in PyCharm using project name

Tags: python, pycharm

I have split my python code in different folders and I'd like to treat them as separate projects in PyCharm. Let's say one project (folder) is called 'lib' and I have `lib/utils.py` in it. The other one is called app and I have `app/utils.py` and `app/app.py`.

I know that I can add the project 'lib' as dependency for the project 'app' but then in app.py PyCharm only allows my import to look like:

```
from utils import some_util
```

I believe PyCharm treats app and lib as two source folders and adds `app/utils.py` to the PYTHONPATH as 'utils'.

When I deploy my app, I would preserve the same directory structure, hence I'd like to write my import like this:

```
from app.utils import some_util
```

So it works when I run it from the parent of the app and lib folders.

How can I use this import structure in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

You may add **init**.py file in your folder to initial the module.

for ex.
in folder utils, you can make your file like a.py, b.py and **init**.py

At the pycharm, you can load the module in the folder utils
 just import utils.a as a or from utils.a import utial_a

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I have __init__.py in the folders, still if I write 'import utils.a' , PyCharm doesn't handle it as the contents of the utils directory are resolved themselves, not the utils directory.